# Public IP address to internal IP address Mapping on Watchguard firewall XTM 5 series

Tags: networking, router

How do I configure NAT Mapping on Watchguard firewall with public ip address given by the ISP to internal web server private IP address? Many thanks.

Public IP address ---> Internal Web Server IP address (192.168.1.3 port 80)

Answer (score 0):

By following this documentation:

http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/wsm/xtm_11/en-US/index.html#cshid=en-US/nat/nat_static_config_about_c.html

Brief version:

- Add a firewall policy for type HTTP-Proxy (or HTTP, but that offers less protection)
- From address "Any-External"
- To address: New S-NAT

  - Give the S-NAT a name
  - Use the firewall's public address
  - For the internal address put 192.168.1.3
- Choose the Webblocker type to HTTP.Server, if applicable
- Save and quit